# Database table gets locked when executing the stored procedure

Tags: database, db2, database-administration

Whenenver the below stored procedure is called, I get table in use exception.

Below is the code for stored procedure,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_BATCHFILE_REPORT_GET001 (
    IN countryCode CHAR(2),
    IN reportFileID BIGINT
    )
RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
SET OPTION COMMIT=*CS
P1: BEGIN
DECLARE cc CHAR(2);
DECLARE fid BIGINT;

-- Declare cursor
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM CPS_FILE
        WHERE COUNTRYCODE = cc
            AND ReportFileID = fid
        AND ReportGenerated = 'P'
        AND Accepted <> '';

SET cc = countryCode;
SET fid = reportFileID;

UPDATE cps_file SET ReportGenerated = 'P'
        WHERE COUNTRYCODE = cc
            AND ReportFileID = fid
        AND ReportGenerated <> 'Y'
        AND Accepted <> '';

-- Cursor left open for client application
OPEN cursor1;
END P1 @
```

I am using DB2 as database, no other process is running at the same time, which could access the table used in the stored procedure.

I get the following error,
 Row or object CPS_FILE in CPSDATA type *FILE in use.

Please advice.

Comment: I'm not much of a SP expert, but it looks like you are locking the CPS_FILE table when you create that cursor.  The subsequent UPDATE statement therefore fails.

Comment: Hi, I think the issue is in the update, and there should be a trigger that uses cpd_file, and then your update cannot be executed. Remember to provide us the SQL code in order to understand better your problem.

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to accomplish here?  It looks like you're attempting to get back a list of all rows that would have been updated  by the update statement.; if so, and your version of DB2 supports it, you may want to look at the [data change table reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000875.html) section.  And how are you expecting to have the cursor return any rows, if `cc` and `fid` haven't been set yet?  And potentially globally setting the commit level that way may not be helping any, either.

Comment: First thing I'd change is the names of the parms to be `cc` and `fid`. Then I'd get rid of the two `DECLAREs` and the two ` SETs`. Those do nothing but confuse everything; unless `COUNTRYCODE` and `ReportFileID` are not column names, in which case the SP doesn't make clear sense.